# Matlab GUI - Support for DDE

Tags: matlab, user-interface, dde

How can I use DDE in MATLAB GUI? Is there any support for that? I mean to embed an excel spreadsheet as to say "Microsoft Excel Worksheet Object" with most of the application    functionalities(Commands,etc) to be available when firing it up in MATLAB GUI?

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to read this: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_external/example-reading-excel-spreadsheet-data.html

Comment: Although this info accounts for linking and data exchange between matlab and excel by using actxserver, it is not what I asked for. I want the spreadsheet to be as an embedded object in GUI.